# What's the Google App Engine equivalent of ASP.NET's Server.Transfer?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Server.Transfer is sort of like a Redirect except instead of requesting the browser to do another page fetch, it triggers an internal request that makes the request handler "go to" another request handler.

Is there a Python equivalent to this in Google App Engine?

Edit: webapp2

Comment: Which Python framework are you using?

Comment: Answer will be very specific to whatever python request routing packaing you use, webapp/webapp2, flask, pyramid, bobo, etc....

Answer (score 2):

With most Python frameworks the request handler is simply a function: I should imagine you can just **import** the actual handler function you want to use and pass it the parameters you received in the current handler function.

In Django (for example): you usually have a function that takes at least 1 parameter, the `request` object. You should be able to simply import the next handler and then return the result of executing it. Something like:

```
def actual_update_app_queue_settings(request):
  return HttpResponse()

def update_app_queue_settings(request):
   return actual_update_app_queue_settings(request):
```

For the framework you've mentioned, probably something like this:

```
class ProductHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, product_id):
        self.response.write('You requested product %r.' % product_id)

class ProductHandler2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, product_id):
        nph = ProductHandler()
        nph.initialize(request, response)
        nph.get(product_id)
```

I'm fudging that by looking at http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html: it looks reasonable. If you're using route annotations I'm honestly not sure what you do, but that might do it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you just have to call the corresponding method.
For being more specific... Which flavour of AppEngine are you using? Java, Python, Go... Php?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java/servlet, then the "forward" is

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/newurl").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Question is tagged with Python :)

Comment: Thanks, sorry, forgot to mention Python in the question. I couldn't find a Python equivalent. Do you know if there is one?

Comment: I tagged it Python after Peter's answer. Sorry for the sloppiness.